# Hidden div content, do search engines consider this content or ignore it?

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery and SEO (hidden div's)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102430/jquery-and-seo-hidden-divs)

What if I added a hidden div tag inside it some content text, does search engines look into this div?

Example:

```
<div style="display:none">some text</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if you are worried about a search engine seeing it or if you want to "cheat" it, but don't try to cheat the search engine. Eventually the algorithms they use will catch on and your site may be banned.

Comment: It is well answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102430/jquery-and-seo-hidden-divs

Comment: @Matt I'm not trying to cheat, I'm using jQuery to hide and show some content to interact with the user nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be indexed but can be frowned upon by Google if you are hiding/showing content for SEO reasons. In other words, what Google sees should be what the user sees when clicking the link.

have a look on this discussion at google form:

http://groups.google.com/group/Google_Webmaster_Help-Indexing/browse_thread/thread/fd91a80997e531b2/e0fe0c574aa44b8d?lnk=gst&q&pli=1

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends who you ask :)

Google is pretty smart and *does* take CSS into account in certain ways. As far as I can tell they seem pretty good at distinguishing between genuinely useful (to the user) content that is hidden and complete spam content hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get an idea of what the search engine sees is the use lynx http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)

Comment: I've tried lynx, pretty awesome :D