# How to make a particular div non crawl able on a html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was trying to block a particular div so that Google cannot crawl it. I have searched lot regarding this and got some solutions. But in some blogs these methods are not good for SEO point of view .

1. Use display:none in css
2. Visibility:hidden
3. Use Z index

Thanks to this link [Methos to hide text](http://www.shimonsandler.com/14-methods-to-hide-text/)

Please help me to find out some alternative to make a particular div non crawl able.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342627/hide-text-or-div-from-crawlers

Answer (score 1):

Put googleon/googleoff tags to tell Google when to start and stop indexing various parts of the web document:

```
<p>This is normal (X)HTML content that will be indexed by Google.</p>
<!--googleoff: index-->
<p>This (X)HTML content will NOT be indexed by Google.</p>
<!--googleon: index>
```

Comment: googleon/googleoff tags are not working they are out of date I had read somewhere

Comment: @Kanika did you checked the official google documentation I have linked?

Comment: @sc3w Yes I did but my SEO Manager is telling not to use googleon/googleoff it will problem and it is temporary solution