# Jquery page transitions and SEO

Tags: jquery, css

for a few of the brochure sites I'm currently working on I've found it quite pleasing to have a very short fade in and out as the page loads.  I do this by using display none on the body and then triggering the fade on document ready with jQuery.

My Question is this, will this negatively affect the page from an SEO perspective ?

Please note the following :
 - I will serve non javascript users a notice and essentially a single column 'print' stylesheet, with all of the sites functionality hidden, so thats not a concern.
 - I'm fully aware that some may deem creating this delay "bad practice" and I'm not interested in having that discussion, please answer the question directly, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick look in Google this seems to be fine and will not affect your SEO

See

http://tomaltman.com/does-the-google-bot-index-css-hidden-divs/

[Does google index pages with hidden divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514659/does-google-index-pages-with-hidden-divs)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/Google_Webmaster_Help-Indexing/_ZGoCZflMbI

Comment: thanks, hidden divs sure and those articles are quite helpful, note that I'm putting display:none on the "body" tag and hiding everything.  I suppose I could use a section#wrapper inside the body to avoid doing that or move it off the page.

Comment: either way it shouldn't matter