# Google maps API robots.txt file blocking crawl

Tags: google-maps, seo, robots.txt, googlebot

I have used Google maps,places,directions javascript API in my web application. Application loads different places based on user input by making ajax call to the google api. Fortunately Google is able to crawl the ajax lately.

When I was checking the URLs in the Googles webmaster tool **'Fetch as Google'** feature, the response is like below

[image: blocked resources]

[image: Fetch as Google]

**Here is the google maps api robots.txt file**

[image: Google Robots.txt]

Is google maps api blocking Google bot? in that case please suggest me what would be approach should I follow to to get the page content?

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437504/googles-crawler-wont-understand-own-maps-how-to-workaround something like `if (navigator.userAgent !== 'Googlebot') {
   // load the map and other stuff
} else {
   // show a picture where the map should be or do nothing.
}` this may help , also userAgents https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en

Comment: I'm curious, if Googlebot had been able to access those .js files would it have made any difference? Does it execute the code it finds in them and index/crawl the resulting content?

Comment: Yes, google bot can follow ajax calls, crawl and index. If you see loading button disabled in the screenshot, it was done through js. I have some other pages , which has some ajax calls, google bot shows screen exactly as user sees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We took contact with Google Maps Support and they confermed it was a bug at their side! However, no statements were made about when we could expect a fix.

Comment: awesome. Now google maps robots.txt not blocking crawlers. thanks a lot.